# Confusion on defining custom Style and theme

Tags: android, styles, themes

**Define custom style ,we do like this**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
   <style name="CustomFontStyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">
      <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
      <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
      <item name="android:capitalize">characters</item>
      <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
      <item name="android:textSize">12pt</item>
      <item name="android:textColor">#00FF00</item>/> 
   </style>
</resources>
```

**and define custom theme we do like this**

```
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    ...
</style>
```

My confusion is why the parent attribute is "android:Theme.Light" rather than ***@android:style/Theme.Light*** ？

Any help would be wonderful.
 Thanks！

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"android:Theme.Light" is a short type of "@android:style/Theme.Light", you can use the latter one instead of the former one when you define your style or theme.

Similarly, "@android:style/TextAppearance" can be shortened as "android:TextAppearance" too.

Because a style's parent must be a style, the "style" word can be omitted without mislead the build tool.

Remember that you can't omit the "style" word when you apply your style to your View or Activity.